# ADFS 2.0 How to get wfresh="0" to work with SAMLP?

Tags: saml, adfs, ws-federation

I'm using ADFS as STS to access an external SAML Idp, and I need to force authentication to happen in certain use cases. This seems to be possible only through modified IdpInitiatedSignOnPage as suggested in

AD FS 2.0 Sign-In Pages Customization Overview (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee895361.aspx)

```
SignOnRequestParameters parameters = new SignOnRequestParameters();

// Require the user to authenticate.
parameters.ForceAuthentication = true;
```

My Question is, how do I get this to work when using the wsfederation? Specifying wfresh="0" seems to have no effect at all? What am I missing? Is this use case even supported?

Answer (score 0):

The question is somewhat confusing - you ask about SAML but then use wfresh which is for WS Federation only.

The SAML equivalent IIRC is ForceAuthentication.

Have you tried setting the freshness option in the federatedAuthentication section of the web.config?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, but that's exactly where the problem lies. I'm using wsfedration with ADFS as a gateway to access SAML IdP. The ADFS translates wsfedration request to SAMLP internally, but it seems to ignore wfresh parameter and I'm unable to force user to sign in.